# curl script works on command line but java returns "couldn't connect to host"

Tags: java, bash, curl

I use a `curl` call in a shell script, `curlerWS.sh`, to connect to SOAP, REST, and RESTful web services.  The issue I have currently is with a SOAP call, specifically connecting to a Sharepoint endpoint, *when the script is called from java*.

`curlerWS.sh` works as intended when called from a subshell (another shell script).  It returns the expected XML response from sharepoint.

The `curl` command it calls also works interactively in the main shell.

However, when I call `curlerWS.sh` from a java class (running in Tomcat on the same server as the aforementioned shell calls) using the same parameters, curl returns `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

This call has worked in the past with other sharepoint endpoints which are currently down for maintenance.

I believe I've ruled out proxies.  When I set the proxy explicitly in the `ProcessBuilder` I get an error from the proxy server, referring to erroneous usage of it to reach an internal site.

The `curlerWS.sh` call in the script:

```
curlerWS.sh -X -s https://host.domain/sites/site/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx \
-f "studies.xml" \
-u "domain\user" \
-p pass \
-a ntlm \
-q '<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><listName>{FAC53F9A-F7DC-4511-A675-F23B479C87CB}</listName><viewName></viewName><query></query><viewFields></viewFields><rowLimit>0</rowLimit><queryOptions><QueryOptions></QueryOptions></queryOptions></GetListItems>' \
-t http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems
```

The `curl` call in `curlerWS.sh`:

```
curl \
-s \
"$DEBUG" \            # -v
--show-error \
-k \
--$AUTH \             # --ntlm
-A "basic" \
-u "$USER:$PASS" \
$FILE \               # -o output
-H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"  \
-H "SOAPAction: $ACTION" \
-d "$DATA" \          #<?xml ...><soapenv:Envelope...>...</soapenv:Envelope>
"$SOURCE"
```

The `curl` call on the command-line:

```
curl -s -v --show-error -k --ntlm -A "basic" -u "domain\user:pass" -o studies.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems" -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><listName>{FAC53F9A-F7DC-4511-A675-F23B479C87CB}</listName><viewName></viewName><query></query><viewFields></viewFields><rowLimit>0</rowLimit><queryOptions><QueryOptions></QueryOptions></queryOptions></GetListItems></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>' "https://host.domain/sites/site/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
```

The `curlerWS.sh` call in java:

```
ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add(new Finder().getEnv(YADA_BIN)+CURL_EXEC);
args.add("-X"); 
args.add("-s");
args.add(soapSource+soapPath);
args.add("-u");
args.add(soapDomain+"\\"+soapUser);
args.add("-p");
args.add(soapPass);
args.add("-a");
args.add(soapAuth);
args.add("-q");
args.add(soapData);
args.add("-t");
args.add(soapAction);
String[] cmds = args.toArray(new String[0]);
l.debug("Executing soap request via script: "+Arrays.toString(cmds));
String s = null;
try
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    l.debug(pb.environment().toString());
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader si = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((s = si.readLine()) != null)
    {
        l.debug(s);
        if(null == result)
        {
            result = "";
        }
        result += s;
    }
    si.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    String msg = "Unable to execute NTLM-authenticated SOAP call using system call to 'curl'.  Make sure the curl executable is still accessible.";
    throw new YADAAdaptorException(msg,e);
}
```

The java `args` array values reported in the log (the first call to `l.debug`)

```
Executing soap request via script: [/apps/bioinfo/dev/bin//curlerWS.sh, -X, -s, http://host.domain/sites/site/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx, -u, domain\user, -p, pass, -a, ntlm, -q, <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>{FAC53F9A-F7DC-4511-A675-F23B479C87CB}</listName><rowLimit>10000</rowLimit></GetListItems>, -t, http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems]
```

Comment: "Could not connect to host" sounds like a network problem. Can you perform other networking operations from inside Java? Try pinging this host or an IP address like 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 0):

After several iterative changes to the configuration, the answer was effectively that my java code was doing a few things wrong.  Regrettably, so was I.

First, the different methods of execution of the SOAP request were not in fact identically configured.  To wit:

The shell and subshell versions were identical.

However, at first, the java version contained a slightly modified version of the soapBody.
The correct markup:

```
<GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>{FAC53F9A-F7DC-4511-A675-F23B479C87CB}</listName><viewName></viewName><query></query><viewFields></viewFields><rowLimit>10</rowLimit><queryOptions><QueryOptions></QueryOptions></queryOptions></GetListItems>
```

The original markup:

```
<GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>{FAC53F9A-F7DC-4511-A675-F23B479C87CB}</listName><rowLimit>10</rowLimit></GetListItems>
```

I've experienced different results when excluding `viewFields` and `queryOptions` in various sharepoint incarnations.  In this case, including them, even empty, seems necessary.  Excluding them returns a sharepoint error referring to `unexpected value` or some such.  However, I wasn't even getting to this point when I noticed that discrepancy, because of the other errors.

Next, I noticed, upon inspecting the trace output of the shell calls that the webserver address was referring to port `443`.  By excluding the port from the host config in the java call, java was defaulting to port `80` which was unreachable with the `http` protocol.

After correcting the port configuration error, by explicitly setting it to `443`, the curl response was no longer failing per say, but was returning, instead, an empty response.

This was because the secure `https` protocol designation was being rewritten to be insecure.  Specifically, `https` was reverting to `http` in the java call.

A refactoring of the java code to retain `https` was the ultimate fix.  I was also able to omit the explicit port config, because with `https`, the server redirects from port 80 to 443.

Thanks for your views and comments!